# Divergence structure equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Consider Laplace's equation with potential function $c$: $$-\Delta u + cu = 0, \tag{$*$}$$ and the divergence structure equation $$-\operatorname{div}(aDv)=0, \tag{$**$}$$ where the function $a$ is positive.
>
> (a) Show that if $u$ solves $(*)$ and $w > 0$ also solves $(*)$, then $v:=u/w$ solves $(**)$ for $a:=w^2$.
>
> (b) Conversely, show that if $v$ solves $(**)$, then $u:=va^{1/2}$ solves $(*)$ for some potential $c$.

I only know so far that as $u$ and $w$ solve $(*)$, we have $$-\Delta u + cu=0 \text{ and } -\Delta w + cw = 0.$$
How may I prove the divergence structure equation? I am confused with differentiating with the $\text{div}$ operator.

---

My work so far for part (b):

If $v$ solves $(**)$, then $-\operatorname{div}(aDv)=0$. So

\begin{align*}
D \cdot(a Dv)=a^{1/2}\Delta v - v \Delta (a^{1/2})=0.
\end{align*}

Also, given $u := va^{1/2}$, I find
$$\Delta u = \frac 12a^{-1/2} DaDv + a^{1/2} \Delta v + \frac 12 D(va^{-1/2})+\frac 12va^{-1/2}\Delta a.$$

How can I apply $-\operatorname{div}(aDv)=0$ to the expression $-\Delta u+cu$ and prove that it is equal to $0$?

---

More work so far in part (b):

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\Delta u &= \nabla \cdot \nabla(a^{1/2}v) \\
&= \nabla \cdot \left[\frac{v\nabla a+2a\nabla v}{2a^{1/2}} \right] \\
&= \frac{(\nabla \cdot (v\nabla a+2a\nabla v))(2a^{1/2})- (v\nabla a+2a\nabla v)(\nabla\cdot(2a^{1/2}))}{4a} \\
&=\frac{(\nabla \cdot (v\nabla a)+2\cancelto{0}{\nabla \cdot (a\nabla v)})(2a^{1/2})- (v\nabla a+2a\nabla v)(\nabla\cdot(2a^{1/2}))}{4a} \\
&= \frac{(\nabla v \cdot \nabla a+v \cdot \Delta a)(2a^{1/2})- (v\nabla a+2a\nabla v)(2(\nabla\cdot a^{1/2}))}{4a}
\end{align}

Comment: Start by calculating $\nabla\cdot (a\nabla v)) = \nabla a \cdot \nabla v + a \Delta v$ for $a=w^2$ and $v=u/w$ (Hint: You should get something along the lines of $w \Delta u - u \Delta w$). From here you can use that $u$ and $w$ satisfy the Laplace equation to finish it off.

Comment: To be sure: From multivariable calculus, we have $\operatorname{div} F = \nabla \cdot F$. So can $v = v/w$ simply regarded as a vector, so we can simply replace the $F$ I said above with $aDv$?

Comment: $v$ is a scalar. $\nabla v$ is a vector and $a\nabla v$ is a vector. The rule for taking the divergence of a scalar times a vector (such as $a\nabla v$) is: $\vec{\nabla}\cdot (a\vec{V}) = \vec{\nabla} a \cdot \vec{V} + a \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{V}$. [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Properties) for example.

Comment: ...and the answer to your question is yes. $F = aDv$ (I'm assuming $D=\nabla$) is a vector so you have $\text{div} F = \nabla \cdot (a\nabla v)$

Comment: Yes, $D = \nabla$; my textbook only uses $D$. Am I doing this right so far? $$\nabla \cdot(w^2 \nabla v)=(\nabla \cdot w^2)\nabla \cdot (v/w))+w^2 \Delta(u/w)$$ Do I need to now employ quotient rule for computing $\nabla \cdot (u/w)$ and $\Delta \cdot (u/w)$?

Comment: Exactly! However it turns out it is easier to not expand the divergence until the end. I.e first write $w^2\nabla v = w^2\nabla (u/w) = w^2[1/w\nabla u - u/w^2 \nabla w]$ (this is just the quotient rule for differentiation) so $w^2\nabla v = w\nabla u - u\nabla w$. Now take the divergence using the rule above and you are there.

Comment: Sorry, there was a slight mistake in your calculation above: $\nabla \cdot (w^2\nabla v) = \nabla w^2 \cdot \nabla(u/w) + w^2 \Delta(u/w) $

Comment: Note that $u,v$ are scalars so $\nabla \cdot u $ does not have a meaning. I'm using the 3rd formula [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Properties) to write out $\nabla \cdot (w^2\nabla v)$. In this expression $\varphi = w^2$ and ${\bf F} = \nabla v$ (in the notation of the wiki page)

Comment: I think I figured it out with your helpful guidance (see my posted answer please).

Comment: Very good. The answer is correct!

Comment: There is also a part (b) to the problem; I am asked to prove the converse direction. Is there any way I can continue? (I updated my work but I got stuck.)

Comment: For 2) start with the equation for $\Delta u = \Delta (\sqrt{a}v) = \nabla\cdot\left[\frac{v\nabla a + 2a\nabla v}{2\sqrt{a}}\right]$. This is on the form $\nabla\cdot \left(\frac{A+B}{C}\right)$ where $\nabla\cdot B = 0$ is the condition you have. Expand the term but keep the $B$-term intact (i.e. don't split it up into the two factors it has). Then you can remove the $\nabla\cdot B$ term and after simplifying you will get something like $\Delta u  = f(a) u$. Thus if $c=f(a) = k\frac{2a\Delta a - (\nabla a)^2}{a^2}$ for a constant $k$ you have to find then $u$ is a solution.

Comment: Before I proceed following the rest of your response, is there a potential algebraic error I'm making in the quotient rule? I got something *slightly* different from yours: $$\nabla (a^{1/2}v)=\frac{(\frac 12 a^{-1/2} \nabla a)v-a^{1/2} \nabla v}{(a^{1/2})^2}=\frac{v \nabla a - 2a \nabla v}{2a^{3/2}}$$Particularly, I got a $-$ sign in the numerator and $3/2$ exponent in the denominator instead of your $+$ sign and $1/2$ exponent.

Comment: Yes. The correct is $\nabla(a^{1/2} v) = (a^{1/2})(\nabla v) + (v)(\frac{1}{2}a^{-1/2}\nabla a)$ (since $(x^{n})' =  nx^{n-1}$)

Comment: Ohhh ... why was I thinking of $\nabla(a^{1/2}/v)$? :O I obviously needed to use product rule for $\nabla(a^{1/2}v)$; I looked at your result and must have thought the quotient rule was used. Sorry about that. I will continue working on this.

Comment: Hi @Winther, I had been working on this on my own still. I don't know why, but I am still stuck on finding $\Delta u$, even when following your hints. The quotient rule with the $\nabla$ operator gets messy pretty quickly, IMO. (Please see my question for the updated work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part b) we take $u=\sqrt{a}v$ and calculate

$$\Delta u = \nabla\cdot(\nabla(\sqrt{a}v)) = \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{v\nabla a + 2 a\nabla v}{2\sqrt{a}}\right) = \\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\nabla \cdot \left(v\nabla a \right) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\nabla \cdot \left(2a\nabla v \right) + (v\nabla a + 2 a\nabla v)\cdot \nabla\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)$$

The first term on the bottom line above is

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\nabla \cdot \left(v\nabla a \right)  = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}(\nabla v \cdot \nabla a + v\Delta a)$$

The second term is zero since $v$ satisfy $\nabla \cdot \left(v\nabla a \right) = 0$ and finally the third term is

$$(v\nabla a + 2 a\nabla v)\cdot \nabla\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} = -\frac{1}{4a\sqrt{a}}(v\nabla a + 2 a\nabla v)\cdot \nabla a = -\frac{1}{4a\sqrt{a}}(v(\nabla a)^2 + 2 a\nabla v\cdot \nabla a)$$

Adding the three terms above we get

$$\Delta u = v\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}(\Delta a) -\frac{1}{4a\sqrt{a}}((\nabla a)^2)\right) = u\left(\frac{2a\Delta a-(\nabla a)^2}{4a^2}\right)$$

which shows that $u = \sqrt{a}v$ satisfy the equation $\Delta u = cu$ where

$$c =\frac{2a\Delta a-(\nabla a)^2}{4a^2} $$

Comment: This is exactly what I got. There is a comment I found on a solution sheet saying that c should be laplacian(sqrt(a)) but that does not match. I wonder if c is the laplacian of some other expression of a.

Answer (score 4):

We have 
\begin{align}
w^2 Dv &= w^2 D(u/w) \\
&= w^2 \left(\frac{w Du - u Dw}{w^2} \right) \\
&=wDu-uDw.
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
D \cdot (w^2 Dv) &= D \cdot (w Du-uDw) \\
&= w \Delta u-u \Delta w \\
&= w(cu)-u(cw) \\
&=0.
\end{align}
Thus, $-\operatorname{div}(w^2 Dv)=0$.